# Compare lists for differences

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, tty

I'm trying to create a text editor based in my python interpreter. The environment is sandboxed so I can't use my file system or command line. I have input working, I just need to figure out how to update the screen.

```
import os, sys, tty

# Active text file
text = [''] * int(os.environ.get('PS_TTY_ROWS'))

# Cursor position
cursor = cursor_x, cursor_y = 1, 1

# Allow instant recipt of inputs
tty.setraw(sys.stdin)
sys.stdout.write('\033[H\033[J')

# Main input loop
while True:
    key = sys.stdin.read(1)
    sys.stdout.write('\033[H' + str(text))
    if key == '\x1b':
        key = sys.stdin.read(2)
        if key == '[A': # Up
            cursor_y = sorted((1, len(text) - 1, cursor_y - 1))[1]
        elif key == '[B': # Down
            cursor_y = sorted((1, len(text) - 1, cursor_y + 1))[1]
        elif key == '[C': # Right
            cursor_x = sorted((1, len(text[cursor_y - 1]) + 1, cursor_x + 1))[1]
        elif key == '[D': # Left
            cursor_x = sorted((1, len(text[cursor_y - 1]) + 1, cursor_x - 1))[1]
    elif key == '\x7f': # Backspace
        if cursor_x > 1:
            text = ('\r'.join(text[:cursor_y - 1]) + '\r' + text[cursor_y - 1][:cursor_x - 2] + text[cursor_y - 1][cursor_x - 1:] + '\r' + '\r'.join(text[cursor_y:])).split('\r')
            cursor_x -= 1
    else:
        text[cursor_y - 1] = text[cursor_y - 1][:cursor_x - 1] + key + text[cursor_y - 1][cursor_x - 1:]
        cursor_x = sorted((1, len(text[cursor_y - 1]) + 1, cursor_x + 1))[1]
        if key == '\r':
            cursor_y += 1
            cursor_x = 1
    text = '\r'.join(text).split('\r')
    sys.stdout.write('\033[J\033[H' + '\n'.join(text[:min(len(text), int(os.environ.get('PS_TTY_ROWS')) - 1)]))
    sys.stdout.write('\033[' + str(cursor_y) + ';' + str(min(len(text[cursor_y - 1]) + 1, cursor_x)) + 'H')
```

My current method of redrawing the entire screen on refresh but it is a bit slower than I'd like and I'm hoping to replace it with a method of only redrawing what's changed, is there a way to compare two lists (a copy of the text before input and the text list after input) for changes to see what to redraw without using loops or list comprehensions?

Comment: "is there a way to compare two lists (a copy of the text before input and the text list after input) for changes to see what to redraw without using loops or list comprehensions?" Why don't you want to use loops or list comprehensions? What kind of "comparison" do you actually want to do - what should the result be, and what is the rule that tells you how to compute that result?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel The aim would be to get either a list of the changed indices/slices in each string or to get the indices of the changed strings in the list. I'm avoiding looping through the text list since it would be slower than my current method of joining and printing the entirety of the list.

Comment: "since it would be slower than my current method of joining and printing the entirety of the list." Why do you believe so? Did you try it? Do you have an actual performance concern?

Comment: I haven't explicitly tested that assumption, so it could be wrong, it just seems that print statements would be faster than loops. Using the method posted above text jitters in and out of view when typing due to the text being redrawn, which I'm trying to avoid. I'm also trying to find out if there is a method to compare lists like mentioned in the post in general out of mere curiosity, since I haven't found it anywhere else.

Comment: print statements don't actually do any of the computation; outputting stuff is *very slow* compared to number-crunching no matter how you do it; and it is *rarely* obvious what will be fastest in a computer program as long as you have a sane algorithm. Even then, improving the big-O complexity of *something that isn't the bottleneck in practice* might not be noticeable.

Comment: Also, you still haven't clarified: *what does "compare lists" mean for you*? Unless you are using the word in the strict sense, to mean that one list should be judged to be "less than" or "greater than" the other, the only thing that "compare" says is that there are two inputs to the process. It doesn't say *anything* about what the process actually is, or how the outputs relate to the input.

Comment: Anyway, please consider using more sophisticated tools for this, such as `curses` or one of its many, many variants; or studying event-driven programming in order to use a GUI toolkit (Python comes with a basic one, called `tkinter`). Just outputting ANSI codes isn't designed for performance, and there are any number of things that might make this appear slow that are *not within your control from within Python code*.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the efficiency of print statements compared to loops. The goal of the list comparison would be the output I mentioned in my first comment, somewhat like an xor for two bytes. I have considered both `curses` and `tkinter` for my purposes, unfortunately my environment isn't set up to support `tkinter` and `curses` threw and error about a missing `_curses` module, I perhaps should have mentioned this in the post. Otherwise curses would be perfect.